# On what grounds is a divorce ok, any?

Tags: divorce

On what grounds is a divorce ok, any?
Divorce is complicated and Hashem has a plan with the marriage between a man and a woman.

Comment: What do you mean when you claim that divorce is complicated?

Comment: See the last Mishna in Gittin

Comment: Link for the mishah http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Gittin.9.10?with=all    related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28554/reasons-for-divorcing-a-woman-sourcing-a-chiddush#

Comment: [Last Mishna in Gittin](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01125.html#HtmpReportNum0074_L2) - בֵּית שַׁמַּאי אוֹמְרִים, לֹא יְגָרֵשׁ אָדָם אֶת אִשְׁתּוֹ אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן מָצָא בָהּ דְּבַר עֶרְוָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים כד), כִּי מָצָא בָהּ עֶרְוַת דָּבָר. וּבֵית הִלֵּל אוֹמְרִים, אֲפִלּוּ הִקְדִּיחָה תַבְשִׁילוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (שם), כִּי מָצָא בָהּ עֶרְוַת דָּבָר. רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא אוֹמֵר, אֲפִלּוּ מָצָא אַחֶרֶת נָאָה הֵימֶנָּה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (שם), וְהָיָה אִם לֹא תִמְצָא חֵן בְּעֵינָיו:

Answer (score 2):

[Shulchan aruch even ezer 119.3](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.119.3)

> one should not divorce his first wife unless he found her cheating. hagah: Aside from this, the rabbis said: "if someone divorces his first wife, the alter cries tears upon him". This is specifically talking in their days (time of the talmud), when they frequently divorced a woman even against her will (this is when the alter cries). but if she consents it is permitted. You should try to not rush into divorcing your first wife, but the second wife, if you dislike her, you can divorce her.

4

> a woman who is evil in her opinions (i.e immodest and promiscuous) and is not modest like jewish daughters are supposed to be, it is a positive commandment to divorce her.

---

[154.10](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.154.10?with=all)

> If a man married a woman and stayed with her for ten years and did not produce children, he must divorce her and give her Ketubah, or marry another woman who can bear children. If he is unwilling, we force him to divorce. If he said, "I will not have intercourse with her. I will live with her with witnesses so that I will not be secluded with her." Whether she said this, or he said it, we do not listen; instead we require him to divorce or marry a child bearing woman. Rem"a: Some authorities say that this is true if they had no children at all. If, however, she birthed a viable child, even though he has not yet fulfilled obligation to be fruitful, we do not force him to divorce her. See ([Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer 1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.1.3)), that these days we never force a divorce. A man is believed to say that he knows himself to be sterile, and we do not force him to marry a woman.

See http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.115

---

The wife's grounds (it might be better that women should not read this)

[154](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.154)

---

Hashem has a plan...

מועד קטן יח, ב

> אמר רב משום רבי ראובן בן אצטרובלי מן התורה ומן הנביאים ומן הכתובים מה' אישה לאיש. מהתורה דכתיב (בראשית כד, נ), וַיַּעַן לָבָן וּבְתוּאֵל וַיֹּאמְרוּ מֵה' יָצָא הַדָּבָר. מן הנביאים דכתיב (שופטים יד, ד), וְאָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ לֹא יָדְעוּ כִּי מֵה' הִיא. מן הכתובים (משלי יט, יד), בַּיִת וָהוֹן נַחֲלַת אָבוֹת וּמֵה' אישה מַשְׂכָּלֶת

Mo'ed Katan 18b

> Thus said Rab in the name  of R. Reuben b. Estrobile, from  the Torah, (26)  from  the Prophets and from  the Hagiographa it may be shown that a woman is [destined to] a man by God. From  the Torah: Then Laban and Bethuel answered and said,  The thing proceedeth from  the Lord. (27) But his [Samson's] father and mother knew not that it was of the Lord. (28)  From  the Prophets:  And from  the Hagiographa: House and riches are the inheritance of fathers, but a prudent wife is from the Lord. (29)

(26) The Pentateuch. (27) Gen. XXIV, 50. (28) Judg. XIV,4. (29) Prov. XIX, 14.

---

Hashem is the Shadchan
[בראשית רבה סח ג-ד](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.68.3)

Comment: Not everything from the Talmud is good advise

Comment: @Eagel I do not understand your point

Answer (score -1):

First of all divorce is a mitzvah which can found in Devarim 24:1-4
The reasons for divorce are discussed in meseches gittin 90b

As far as a divine plan for marriage this is in the beginning of Sotah where it says one's spouse is predetermined before you are born.

Comment: As far as a divine plan for marriage see my answer ther is also in moed katon 18b

Comment: _divorce is a mitzvah_ is misleading. It's not like praying or Tefilin or Shabbat.  it's more of a _"if you need to do it, here's how"_ type of Mitzva .

Comment: @DannySchoemann Like shechita for example

Comment: @DannySchoemann it is one of the 613 mitzvas. What's misleading about it? B/c it doesn't sound nice? Sometimes there is also a mitzvah to go to war as well. Mitzvas are commandments not nice things that make us feel good. In the case of divorce sometimes a limb (your other half) becomes infected and in order for both of you to survive there must be a divorce (amputation).

Comment: If a woman asks her husband for a divorce, and he gives her a divorce, do we say hashem decreed they get divorced or do we say she is the one that wanted the divorce ?